# unable to use windows 7 cd key from old machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

So I have a retail (not OEM) Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit license. It's on an old computer that I'm looking to upgrade.

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate DVD but I don't want to use the key on that since that key is unused. I'd rather transfer the key from the old computer to this new one to conserve my licenses. To that end I used http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html to get the key on the old machine.

Problem is...  when I try to enter that key on the new machine - running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit - I get a "The product key is not valid" error.

The product key is valid. It works on the old machine. So why doesn't it work on the new one? Both machines are running Windows 7 Ultimate. The old one is 32-bit and the new one is 64-bit. So what is the problem?

It is my intention to reformat the old computer and then donate it to charity or something idk when the new computer is up and running but if I can't transfer my Windows 7 license then I don't really see the point.

Maybe the software I'm using to get the CD key is giving me the wrong CD key?

Comment: Regular windows 7 ultimate keys should work on both 32bit and 64bit versions. Since both are -ultimate and assuming both are non OEM (post only mnetions that the first is non-OEM) then it should just work.

Comment: Might the PC have been shipped with an OEM version of Windows originally and then been upgraded with a newer Win versions or Ultimate replacing whatever was there before?  IOW, might the software be picking up the old key rather than the Ultimate one for some reason?  Have you tried other similar programs to recover the key?  Magic Jelly Bean for example?

Comment: Further to Steve's comment, you sure it's a standalone key rather than an upgrade key? Also where are you actually entering the key? If it's in the installer, do you have an equivalent 32-bit installer from the same source you could test with?

Comment: Programs designed to discover a Windows 7 license key, can only discover the license key that was used to to activate the installation itself, no other license is discoverable.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg was right - the key was an upgrade key. I had to install Windows XP and then upgrade from that to Windows 7.